# ios - Add device to provisioning Profiles managed by Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I am using a provisioning profile that is "managed by Xcode" and i can't edit it so i can add devices to it, the current profile i'm using is set-up to use Push Notifications, and i want to add another device to test on it, i use Hockey to do that and the other device downloaded the app perfectly, but never receives Push Notifications, although on Parse.com it shows that the device the correctly installed and supposedly receiving notifications, but they never show on the device.

Answer (score 5):

to add a new device to your provisioning profile, go to :

https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action

Then : Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Devices -> Click on the "+" button and add your device.

In Xcode :

Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Select your Apple Id on the left column -> Select your team on the right column -> View details -> Click on the refresh button -> Done

Xcode will automatically update your provisioning profile with the new devices.

As Julian J. Tejera pointed out in the comments section, you might also need to restart Xcode.

Comment: I would like to add that you need to restart Xcode. I was pulling my hair trying to figure out why it wasn't working!